# CSS to Target Anything Larger than a Smart Phone

Tags: css, mobile

There are a few questions on Stack Overflow targeting specific phones, but I'm wondering if there is a trusted media query to target ***anything bigger than a handheld smartphone***.

Excluded:

- iPhone 3G, 3GS, 4, 4S, 5; Android Phones; Windows Phones; etc.

Included:

- iPads and other tablets; desktop computers

Is this rule reliable?

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) {
}
```

Comment: of course this will change again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be better

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

}
```

because there are a lot of handheld devices with `540px` width, but no tablets under `600px` I'm aware of